# Allow console access to physical machines through telnet

Tags: telnet, console, ipmi, supermicro

We have a Super Micro server blade in our lab running a custom OS.The console of the OS can be accessed using the Super Micro web interface. A window gets created by running a .jnlp which needs to be downloaded from the Super Micro web interface. It is extremely cumbersome as you can't scroll etc in the window created by running the .jnlp.

My question is what do I require to configure a telnet access to the console of the OS?

I am not a system administrator. I do know that telnet access can be used to access console, I need some information before I can push the system administrator to get it implemented.